# JavascriptCore compilation

Tags: android, c++, ios, cross-compiling, javascriptcore

for a project, which will be available to iOS and android, i need
to have the compile JavaScriptCore for x86 (so i386 and x86_64) and armv7 (x32 and x64)

but i don't find any tutorial or guide to do it correctly.

Also, as it need it for android, will i have some problem with the CoreFundation ? as i understand, it's a dependencies for the JavaScriptCore.

Last information, i need that the final static library of JavaScriptCore can be use on mac, linux and windows.

Any help ?